# passing variable from php function to another inside class - PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

after creating inside `setUp()` two variables, i cant figure out how should i pass them to second function and use them.

this is my last attempt:
class adRequestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

```
   protected function setUp(){
     $env = \Slim\Environment::mock([
         'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'PUT',
         'REQUEST_URI' => '/foo/bar',
         'QUERY_STRING' => 'abc=123&foo=bar',
         'SERVER_NAME' => 'example.com',
         'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json;charset=utf8',
         'CONTENT_LENGTH' => 15
     ]);
      $request = new \Slim\Http\Request($env);
   }

   function testInitFromHttpRequest_correctConstruction($request, $env){
      $fixture = new AdRequest();
      $fixture->initFromHttpRequest($request, $env);
   }
}
```

i tried doing that by passing them like this as well :

```
   function testInitFromHttpRequest_correctConstruction($request = $this->request, $env = $this->env)
```

but didnt work as well.
i am getting this error:

```
Missing argument 1 for adRequestTest::testInitFromHttpRequest_correctConstruction()
```

but i am passing two arguments like defined in the declaration... what am i missing here?? thx

Comment: you must change the scope of the attribute of the $request and $env at the  class level (as example defined as  $this->env).

Comment: sorry didn't  quite understand...what does it mean change the scope of the attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHPunit framework don't pass any arguments to your function until you don't define a dataprovider (is not your case/scenario).
You can try this modified test case that define as class scope the variable you define in the setup method:

```
class adRequestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{

   private $env;
   private $request;


   protected function setUp(){
     $this->env = \Slim\Environment::mock([
         'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'PUT',
         'REQUEST_URI' => '/foo/bar',
         'QUERY_STRING' => 'abc=123&foo=bar',
         'SERVER_NAME' => 'example.com',
         'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json;charset=utf8',
         'CONTENT_LENGTH' => 15
     ]);
      $this->request = new \Slim\Http\Request($this->env);
   }

   function testInitFromHttpRequest_correctConstruction(){
      $fixture = new AdRequest();
      $fixture->initFromHttpRequest($this->request, $this->env);
      // write here your tests/assertions...
   }
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: thx @Matteo but im still getting this error `adRequestTest::testInitFromHttpRequest_correctConstruction
Undefined variable: env
`...any clue why?? i tried both `$env` and `env`

Comment: Ah! A typo: is not `$this->$env` BUT `$this->env`. I update my answer.

Comment: got it...`     $this->request = new \Slim\Http\Request($this->env);'...thx for help!

Comment: I see another typo in the setup method: `$this->request = new \Slim\Http\Request($this->env);` I don't know if this fix your problem...